# ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

itI have table named **per**.  In the **per** table, I have a field named "fl1" and another field named "fl2".  When updating a record, I want to check if the value of "fl1" has changed". If the value has changed, update the "fl2" column with the new value from "fl1".

I came up with this trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Flag
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE on per
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
BEGIN
  If :New.fl1 != :Old.fl1 Then
        :New.fl2:= :new.fl1;
  End If;
END;
```

I get a "ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers" when I run it

The other option I was thinking about (not sure if it would be efficient), is to simply update the value of "fl2" with the value of "fl1" regardless if the value of "fl1" has changed.

**UPDATE**

Added a "For Each Row" and changed "AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE" for "BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE". It's working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Flag
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on per
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
If :New.fl1 != :Old.fl1 Then
   :New.fl2:= :new.fl1;
End If;
END;
```

Comment: If you have an answer, you should post it *as* an answer, not as an update to your question. You can then (after an enforced delay, IIRC) mark the answer as accepted. This lets people know that you're not still looking for answers.

Comment: Minor note - the error message is incorrect.  There are no 'table-level' triggers; if a trigger is not a row-level trigger, it applies only to the rows affected by the DML statement.  I always see these called 'statement-level triggers.'  Funny about the error message.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

DML triggers are either defined as table level or as row level.

A table level trigger fires once for each operation on the table, so if you update 30 rows then that is one operation as far as a table trigger is concerned. Table triggers do not have insight into which rows are modified, but can be used to log the fact that an operation was carried out.

In this case you need a row level trigger, which requires "FOR EACH ROW" to be included in the trigger definition. The "REFERENCING" clause is optional if you do not want to change the way that you reference the new and old rows.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#BABCIBBJ

Not sure what the point of the exercise here is, though. Have you considered just referencing fl1 instead of fl2?

Comment: Added the "For Each Row". See update in my original post. It's working.  Is my code efficient ?

Comment: Not as efficient as not maintaining two columns with one as a duplicate of the other. Is there a reason for needing fl1 duplicated into fl2?

Comment: It's just a temporary solution before we implement the ability to update the fl2 field.

Comment: David:  Would it be better if I would skip checking if "fl1" has changed and simply update the "fl2" field regardless if "fl1" was changed or not ??

Comment: No, but to be more clear I think I'd break the trigger out into two: one for INSERT and one for UPDATE OF FL1. The insert trigger wil always set FL2, the UPDATE OF FL2 will set it only if the value changes. You can then avoid testing whether NEW != OLD, where you might run into trouble with NULL values.

Answer (score 9):

Final working code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Flag
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on per
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
If :New.fl1 != :Old.fl1 Then
   :New.fl2:= :new.fl1;
End If;
END;
```