# Is there any way we can emulate the way of using :old and :new of row triggers in statement triggers in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Good Day Buddies!

So, here is my Question, it says -

> Write a update, delete trigger on clientmstr table. The System
> should keep track of the records that ARE BEING updated or
> deleted. The old value of updated or deleted records should be
> added in audit_trade table. (Separate implementation using both row
> and statement triggers)

And my solution looks like this -

```
-- For row trigger
create or replace trigger row_trigger
    before delete or update on client_master
    referencing old as old new as new
    for each row
begin
    insert into audit_table values(
    :old.client_id, :old.client_name, :old.client_budget
    );
end;
/
```

---

And as per the question I have to implement the same using **statement trigger** but I couldn't think of a way it can be done. I studied about statement triggers and I learned that we can't use :old and :new here. **Is there any way we can implement the same row trigger method of adding in audit table using statement trigger?** I am just starting out and it's just been two days I started learning PL/SQL. I spend whole day searching everywhere on the internet - tried looking for an example but I am not getting it. Can anyone help?

---

**Edit**

(1) I am using Oracle SQL Developer

(2) As someone suggested in comments - it isn't possible to do this in statement trigger, I think the same. I have to submit my assignment this Saturday. I had a conversation with my teacher - she said it's possible to implement it using statement trigger. I asked her how - but she didn't responded. Then I asked her for a hint and she said this (I'm copy pasting her text)-

> Create a separate table with col as operations and timestamp. Write statement level trigger on insert update and delete operations. The trigger will capture the operation fired and timestamp by inserting values in table.

I am not getting what does that mean or how to do it! Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? The trigger code will be product specific.

Comment: @jarlh I am using Oracle

Comment: @ShreyasChavhan, short answer, level statement triggers are not designed for that. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741342/ora-04082-new-or-old-references-not-allowed-in-table-level-triggers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741342/ora-04082-new-or-old-references-not-allowed-in-table-level-triggers)

Comment: @RobertoHernandez to be honest Roberto, I read every where and found out that it isn't possible and told my class teacher to have a look. She said - it's possible, do it. You have to submit assignment this Saturday.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I have edited the question to explain what exactly happened - can you have a look once more?

Comment: If a lecturer posts this kind of challenge it's worth reviewing recent lecture content for possible ideas. Perhaps the lecturer is hoping you will use a compound trigger? Have a read of https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/a-fresh-look-at-auditing-row-changes

Comment: What your teacher says doesn't seem to make sense. You want to log information per row, so use a row trigger. What would a statement trigger be good for here? I am not saying that it's completely impossible to log information on changed rows in a statement trigger. We could probably use some flashback query here thus looking at the table now and some hours (?) before, but what the heck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a compound trigger.

Create the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE client_master_obj IS OBJECT(
  id     NUMBER,
  name   VARCHAR2(20),
  budget NUMBER(10,2)
);

CREATE TYPE client_master_table IS TABLE OF client_master_obj;
```

Then the trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER client_master_cmp_trigger
FOR DELETE OR UPDATE ON client_master
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  data client_master_table := client_master_table();
AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    data.EXTEND(1);
    data(data.COUNT) := client_master_obj(
                          :OLD.client_id,
                          :OLD.client_name,
                          :OLD.client_budget
                        );
  END AFTER EACH ROW;
AFTER STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audit_table (client_id, client_name, client_budget, trg_type)
    SELECT id,
           name,
           budget,
           'C'
    FROM   TABLE(data);
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE client_master (client_id, client_name, client_budget) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Debra', 400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Emily', 500 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE audit_table (client_id, client_name, client_budget, trg_type) AS
SELECT cm.*, 'X' FROM client_master cm WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Then after:

```sql
UPDATE client_master
SET   client_budget = client_budget + 600
WHERE client_id IN (1, 2);

DELETE FROM client_master WHERE client_id IN (1, 3);
```

Then the audit table contains (with the row trigger also firing for the same changes):

```sql
SELECT * FROM audit_table;
```

> | CLIENT_ID | CLIENT_NAME | CLIENT_BUDGET | TRG_TYPE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Alice | 100 | R |
> | 2 | Beryl | 200 | R |
> | 1 | Alice | 100 | C |
> | 2 | Beryl | 200 | C |
> | 1 | Alice | 700 | R |
> | 3 | Carol | 300 | R |
> | 1 | Alice | 700 | C |
> | 3 | Carol | 300 | C |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83b6ad6f76e4ce1248e769b5f8e426dc)*

Comment: Yep, that's possible. And I love compound triggers. But why would anyone use this approach for the given task, when we can simply log the data in a row trigger right away?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, compound triggers have the benefit of being performance wise much better than row level triggers in scenarios when you update millions of rows at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Same approach using compound trigger, but although is not literally a level statement trigger, because normally they refer to table level triggers.

```
create or replace trigger row_compound_trigger
    for delete or update on client_master
    compound trigger 
    --
    -- an array structure to buffer all the row changes
    --
     type t_row_list is
       table of client_master%rowtype index by pls_integer;
 
     l_audit_rows      t_row_list;
 
     l_operation varchar2(1) :=
         case when updating then 'U'
              when deleting then 'D'
         end;
 
   before statement is
   begin
     --
     -- initialize the array
     --
     l_audit_rows.delete;
   end before statement;
 
   after each row is
   begin
     --
     -- at row level, capture all the changes into the array
     -- this variables use sys_context in case you want to use it ( not needed )
     --
     l_audit_rows(l_audit_rows.count+1).aud_who     := sys_context('USERENV','SESSION_USER');
     l_audit_rows(l_audit_rows.count).aud_when      := sysdate;
     l_audit_rows(l_audit_rows.count).aud_operation := l_operation;
     l_audit_rows(l_audit_rows.count).aud_module    := sys_context('USERENV','MODULE');
 
     if updating then
         l_audit_rows(l_audit_rows.count).client_id        := :new.client_id
         l_audit_rows(l_audit_rows.count).client_name      := :new.client_name
        ... all the fields 
     else
         l_audit_rows(l_audit_rows.count).client_id        := :old.client_id
         l_audit_rows(l_audit_rows.count).client_name      := :old.client_name
         ... all the fields
     end if;
   end after each row;
 
   after statement is
   begin
     --
     -- then at completion, do a single insert of all the rows into our audit table
     --
 
     forall i in 1 .. l_audit_rows.count
        insert into audit_table values l_audit_rows(i);
        l_audit_rows.delete;
   end after statement;
   end;
   /
```